# Define $E_0$ to be the set of points in $E$ for which $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges. Is $E_0$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on a measurable set $E$. Define $E_0$ to be the set of points in $E$ for which $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges. Is $E_0$ measurable?

Note that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges if and only if $\limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\liminf_{n\to \infty} f_n(x).$ Now the map defined as $h(x) = \limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)-\liminf_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ is measurable since each of the limit's are measurable and for each $n$ the map $f_n$ is measurable. Thus we have that $$E_0=\{x \in E \mid \{f_n(x)\} \text{ converges} \} = \{x \in E \mid h(x)=0\}=h^{-1}[\{0\}]$$ which is the preimage of a measurable set under a measurable map. Thus $E_0$ is measurable.

This is how I approached the problem, but the solution had something way different. They had something to do with Cauchy sequences and something where they took the intersection of the union of the intersection over a set $\{x \in E \mid |f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\le \frac{1}{k}\}$.

Is there a error in the approach I took?

Comment: Your approach is correct and much more compact.

Comment: The map $h$ is well-defined provided the limsup and liminf are not both $\infty$ (or $-\infty$). Instead, you know $\limsup f_n$ is measurable and likewise for $\liminf$. It is a general fact that if $f, g:X\to [-\infty, \infty]$ are measurable then the set where $f< g$ is  measurable (hence the same is true if we replace $<$ with any of $ >, \leq, \geq, =$). The point is that this holds even for infinite-valued functions.

Comment: You may need to clarify the meaning of the word "converges". That is, whether "converges" includes the cases $f_n(x)\rightarrow +\infty$ and $f_n(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ because many authors reserve the use of the word "converges" in classical sense (i.e., converges to a real number).